# Heroku | how to read router logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, newrelic

So my typical router log on the **Cedar** platform looks might look like

```
2012-03-22T18:26:34+00:00 heroku[router]: GET [my_url] dyno=web.9 queue=0 wait=0ms service=228ms status=302 bytes=212
2012-03-22T18:26:36+00:00 heroku[router]: GET [my_url] dyno=web.7 queue=0 wait=0ms service=23ms status=200 bytes=360
2012-03-22T18:26:45+00:00 heroku[router]: GET [my_url] dyno=web.30 queue=0 wait=0ms service=348ms status=201 bytes=1
```

I want to confirm my understanding of the terms `queue`, `wait` and `service`

My initial thoughts where that:

- **queue**: The name of the queue if using background_job or resque
- **wait**: how long is the request waiting in the router (Request Queueing in New Relic)
- **service**: how long it actually takes your application to handle the request (not including queing time)

But my **wait** in my logs is ***always*** 0ms.  Even if I have significant backlog.

Are my definitions wrong?

Comment: You say your wait is always 0ms, if the queue is also 0, how do you know you have a backlog outside of this?

Comment: So for example, take serving my crossdomain.xml -- a static file, that on low loads response within 10ms.  At high loads it can be 6000ms+ all the way up to the 30s timeout.  I would expect most of that time to be on queue and wait.

Comment: Also, when I add more dynos, the service time goes down, and vice-versa

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- Queue: The number of requests waiting to be processed by a dyno.
- Wait: The length of time this request sat in the queue before being processed.
- Service: The processing time of the request.

Your total response time will be wait + service.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what "service" means? Does it mean, the time it took to run through whatever scripts before sending a response or is it some internal timer that doesn't have anything to do with the code one wrote?

Comment: "the time it took to run through whatever scripts before sending a response" - This.

Comment: As a caveat, the "service" time seems to take into account network time.  This is most likely similar to how "time-taken" in IIS logs works.  http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/676400bc-8969-4aa7-851a-9319490a9bbb.mspx?mfr=true

I base this off a comparison of some long running items (~20+ sec) according to "service", and comparing with the breakdown given by new relic's "real user monitoring" which indicates nearly 100% of that time is "network" time.

Comment: I can confirm the above - and if you're using Heroku's SSL Endpoint you seem to take a big hit. I see great figures in New Relic for my app, but the logs and Blitz.io both agree that performance collapses at about 50 requests per second per dyno.

Comment: I do not see queue information in Heroku Logs.. do you I need to enable it in some way?  Or have they removed this..

Comment: They may have removed this as they changed the stats after Hipmunk called them out for publishing misleading stats. Have a look at some of Heroku's recent blog posts.

Comment: How did you get these definitions? Can someone provide a URL to some docs? I see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging and it isn't precise with definitions.